# Near by search Function, Java Script

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

currently looking for local restaurants in my area, I am using the nearby search function, it is not taking effect as the result is only bringing back my current location on the emulator, here is what I have for the Nearby Search function (I am using my current location as my latitude and longitude)

```
function initialize() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);

        _map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: latlng,
            zoom: 15
        });
    });  

    var request = {
        location: latlng,
        radius: '500',
        query: ['restaurant']
    };
}

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(_map);
//service.nearbysearch(request, callback);

function createMarker(place) {
      var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: _map,
          position: place.geometry.location
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          infowindow.setContent(place.name);
          infowindow.open(_map, this);
      });
 }

 function callback(results, status) {
     if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
         for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
             var place = results[i];
             createMarker(results[i]);
         }
     }
 }
```

Sorry for all the questions and thanks for the help but a search is still not showing, only the location of where I am at. I have this two lines included in my html file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA8QR7tvuRAV6SkXwLlBsQbAxBAnhuzxMA&libraries=places"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA8QR7tvuRAV6SkXwLlBsQbAxBAnhuzxMA&sensor=true"></script>
```

, I am developing this on Intel XDK using a geo location template

Comment: The geolocation service is asynchronous, you have to use the data inside its callback where/when it is available.  The posted code does not call the nearbySearch function...

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I still don't fully understand what I have to do, could you show me an example if possible? (I'm new to Java script)

Comment: First thing is to actually call the nearbySearch function.

Answer (score 0):

The geolocation service is asynchronous, you have to use the data inside its callback where/when it is available.

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(_map);

function initialize() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

        _map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: latlng,
            zoom: 15
        });
        // call the places service where/when the latlng variable exists.
        var request = {
            location: latlng,
            radius: '500',
            query: ['restaurant']
        };
        service.nearbysearch(request, callback);
    });  
}

function createMarker(place) {
      var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: _map,
          position: place.geometry.location
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          infowindow.setContent(place.name);
          infowindow.open(_map, this);
      });
 }

 function callback(results, status) {
     if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
         for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
             var place = results[i];
             createMarker(results[i]);
         }
     }
 }
```